# CountryData and RailwayGaugeLengths

Tags: built-in-symbols

Looking to see how to extract out just the length for this search:

```
formerSovietUnion = {"Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Belarus", "Estonia", 
"Georgia", "Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Latvia", "Lithuania", 
"Moldova", "Russia", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Ukraine", 
"Uzbekistan"};
totalKilometers = CountryData[#, "RailwayGaugeLengths"][[1, All]] & 
/@ formerSovietUnion
```

Comment: `CountryData[#, "RailwayGaugeLengths"][[1, -1]] & /@ formerSovietUnion`?

Comment: Use `Values` on the result list.

Answer (score 4):

Mapping over entities for properties is less efficient than calling [`EntityValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html) with a list of entities.

Create the country entities.

```
fsu = Thread[Entity["Country", formerSovietUnion]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

There are several metrics available

```
EntityValue[fsu, "RailwayGaugeLengths"]
```

> ```
> {TotalKilometers->845.,BroadGaugeKilometers->845.}
> {TotalKilometers->2122.,BroadGaugeKilometers->2122.}
> {TotalKilometers->5538.,BroadGaugeKilometers->5512.,StandardGaugeKilometers->25.}
> {TotalKilometers->919.,BroadGaugeKilometers->919.}
> {TotalKilometers->1612.,BroadGaugeKilometers->1575.,NarrowGaugeKilometers->37.}
> {TotalKilometers->13700.,BroadGaugeKilometers->13700.}
> {TotalKilometers->470.,BroadGaugeKilometers->470.}
> {TotalKilometers->2298.,BroadGaugeKilometers->2265.,NarrowGaugeKilometers->33.}
> {TotalKilometers->1765.,BroadGaugeKilometers->1743.,StandardGaugeKilometers->22.}
> {TotalKilometers->1138.,BroadGaugeKilometers->1124.,StandardGaugeKilometers->14.}
> {TotalKilometers->87157.,BroadGaugeKilometers->86200.,NarrowGaugeKilometers->957.}
> {TotalKilometers->680.,BroadGaugeKilometers->680.}
> {TotalKilometers->2980.,BroadGaugeKilometers->2980.}
> {TotalKilometers->21655.,BroadGaugeKilometers->21655.}
> {TotalKilometers->3645.,BroadGaugeKilometers->3645.}
> ```

and although its in the name you can check the units directly.

```
EntityValue[EntityProperty["Country", "RailwayGaugeLengths"], "Unit"]
```

> ```
> Kilometers
> ```

You may use [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) to access the values.

Total per country

```
Query[All, "TotalKilometers"]@res
```

> ```
> {845., 2122., 5538., 919., 1612., 13700., 470., 2298., 1765., 1138., 87157., 680., 2980., 21655., 3645.}
> ```

Grand [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)

```
Query[Total, "TotalKilometers"]@res
```

> ```
> 146524.
> ```

Other summary functions

```
Query[{Min, Max, Mean, Median, StandardDeviation}, "TotalKilometers"]@res
```

> ```
> {470., 87157., 9768.27, 2122., 22190.}
> ```

Including visualisations like [`BoxWhiskerChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html)

```
Query[BoxWhiskerChart[#, "Outliers", BarOrigin -> Left] &, "TotalKilometers"]@res
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This might be cleaner as you're able to ditch the `List`, even: ``EntityValue[EntityClass["Country", "FormerSovietUnionMembers"], EntityProperty["Country", "RailwayGaugeLengths"] ]~Lookup~"TotalKilometers"``. On the other hand I was expecting there to be a qualifier to specify the track gauge but it doesn't look like there is.

Answer (score 0):

The result from your code is: 
[image: Result from code]

Applying the function [Values](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) gives

```
totalKilometers // Values
```

[image: result from applying Values]

Finding the total length is then computed through applying [Total](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html)

```
totalKilometers // Values // Total
```

[image: total length]